# How can I solve OutOfMemory issue with Lottie and ViewPager in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I am using lottie compose with ViewPager.

```
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.Asset(tutorial.lottieSrc))
    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)
    val lottieAnimatable = rememberLottieAnimatable()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        lottieAnimatable.animate(
            composition,
            iteration = LottieConstants.IterateForever
        )
    }

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        progress = { progress },
        modifier = Modifier
        .size(220.dp)
    )
```

This causes OutOfMemory.

Each page uses lottie and the average size is around 4MB.

I think it's not that big size. But my guess is, since it's viewpager, it loads duplicate lottile on the memory.

I get this error:

```
Clamp target GC heap from 51MB to 48MB
```

And then when the app crashes.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and -16B until OOM
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.addPendingInvalidationsLocked(Composition.kt:674)
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.drainPendingModificationsLocked(Composition.kt:566)
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recordModificationsOf(Composition.kt:656)
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.recordComposerModificationsLocked(Recomposer.kt:417)
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$recordComposerModificationsLocked(Recomposer.kt:125)
                                at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2.invokeSuspend(Recomposer.kt:499)
                                at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                                at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@b1d76ac, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@abc1f75, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@d2d3b0a, AndroidUiDispatcher@7fb5f7b]
```

Is there any solution for this?

Referes:
https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie/blob/master/android-compose.md

Comment: You might want to edit your question and provide the complete stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: With Jetpack Compose 1.4.0-alpha03  native Pager is added. It accepts pageCount parameter as Accompoaniest had in initial versions. You can try with it to see if it would make any difference as it says it loads pages in memory before you scroll to pages. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.4.0-alpha03

Comment: @Thracian I changed to 1.4.0-alpha03 and still the same. And I added the error message.

Comment: You experienced this with `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager` not the accompaniest one while `beyondBoundsPageCount` is bigger than 0, right? I checked that default value is 0, i changed it to 2 on one my projects

Comment: Yes, I used androidx one and I tried with setting beyondBoundsPageCount 1 and 2. The same problem. @Thracian

Comment: In descrption it says `Pages to load before and after the list of visible pages. Note: Be aware that using a large value for beyondBoundsPageCount will cause a lot of pages to be composed, measured and placed which will defeat the purpose of using lazy loading. This should be used as an optimization to pre-load a couple of pages before and after the visible ones.` but looks like it's not working as expected